# Parameter to be passed through a method

Tags: java

I'm creating a constructor, what I've been told to do is:

- "The `quantity` parameter is to be passed to the `testQuantity` method."
- "Following this a call to the `getPrice` method should be made passing the `productName`
  parameter"

This is what I have so far for this contructor, variables are setup and I just need some help.

```
    public Order (String productName, int quantity) {
        orderNum = orderNum + 1;
        productName = this.productName;
        quantity = testQuantity; 
        if (isValidOrder = true)
```

Comment: You could call `testQuantity` method and `getPrice` method from constructor and pass `quantity` and `productName` respectively.

Comment: And what is your question ?

Comment: How would I do that, how would I pass the quantity parameter to the testQuantity method.

Comment: @RyanMiller See the answer, two methods are invoked from constructor.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you constructor should be something like this:

```
public Order (String productName, int quantity) {
    testQuantity(quantity); //Probably this should return a boolean or throw a exception
    double price = getPrice(productName); //Probably it should return a quantity.
    //other operations needed.
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public Order (String productName, int quantity) {
        orderNum = orderNum + 1;
        productName = this.productName;
        quantity = testQuantity; 
        if (isValidOrder = true)
        .....
        testQuantity(quantity);
        getPrice(productName);
```

And in `testQuantity` and `getPrice` methods receive parameters what you have passed from constructor.

Not sure what is this line of code though `quantity = testQuantity;`

Comment: Sorry, that was regarding a earlier task where I had to assign the `productName` parameter to the `productName` variable.

Comment: @RyanMiller So hope this helps your question.

Comment: receiving the error "cannot find symbol" "symbol: variable testQuantity" on the line of `quantity = testQuantity;`

Comment: @RyanMiller Show the `testQuantity` method signature, most probably you will have arguments defined for it and it is a method. So you should not call it as `testQuantity`. By the way what is the whole point of having that line?

Comment: Sure. `public void testQuantity (int quantity)`

Comment: @RyanMiller So error you were getting denotes to this, as your signature of method is `int quantity`, you must call `testQuantity(<withvalue or parameter name>)`.

Comment: Hi, sorry i still dont fully understand what you are saying, can you explain it a little bit more?

Comment: You were getting error on this line correct? `quantity = testQuantity`? That is because `testQuantity` is a method having one argument. Hence `testQuantity` must be invoked as `quantity = testQuantity(10);`

Answer (score 1):

```
productName = this.productName;
```

Just consider not doing that. Either your instance variable is assigned a value when declared and is already defined upon instantiation - than you can just use its value and the `productName` parameter is useless.
Or it was not give value where it was declared - then it is the constructors job to assign a value to this variable and before that you cannot use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Order (String productName, int quantity){
    // same as you did "orderNum = orderNum + 1" and "orderNum += 1".
    // I added "this" in the beginning because "orderNum" is not a variable
    // you declared in the constructor so it will be from the class.
    // BTW make sure you initialized the variable.
    this.orderNum++;

    // I think you are doing this part by mistake without understanding. So I commented this part.
    // what this code means is: set the value of variable "productName" (that you declared in the
    // method, the first parameter) of the value of variable "this.productName" (that you declared
    // in the root of the class, like orderNum)
    // productName = this.productName;

    // The quantity parameter is to be passed to the testQuantity method.
    // general way to call a method is <method name>(); "()" means execute
    // any information you want to pass as parameter goes inside the parenthesis
    testQuantity(quantity);

    // Following this a call to the getPrice method should be made passing the productName parameter
    // same rules here.
    getPrice(productName);

    // However, you are not storing the values after you calling the methods.
    // if you have any further questions feel free to comment and I will reply asap.
    // Good Luck!
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the in depth explanation for all of those, I will be testing this asap and will let you know how it goes.

Comment: feel free to let me know if you dont understand any part of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Go through following code,

1. Pass the quantity in to the testQuantity method : testQuantity(quantity);
2. Get the price : getPrice(productName);

Good Luck !!!